# What are the trade-offs of writing conventional node modules in ES6 with a babel workflow?

Tags: node.js, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When developing front-end code for the browser, I often use the [es2017 preset](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2017) when transpiling down to a distribution bundle, which allows me all the conveniences of the included transformers. For conventional modules, I usually stick to whatever the required node engine I've specified for that particular module supports.

I would like to start developing these "conventional" modules using babel transformers as well, but I can foresee drawbacks to this, including:

- It might inhibit the debugging workflow (more specifically when working with an IDE)
- The performance of the module might suffer

What's the current state on this matter - would you say it makes sense to use babel in conventional modules given the aforementioned and other trade-offs? What are the pros/cons for your preferred workflow?

Bonus question: What are some reputable modules and/or module authors out there that are already using this technique? I've seen Facebook do it for their react ecosystem but I guess that makes sense since those are mostly modules for the browser.

Comment: It depends a lot on the features you intend to use.

Comment: Mostly syntactic sugar such as object spread etc. as well as more readable flow control using async/await.

Comment: Those won't really affect performance, though (especially for async/await) the transformation can be intensive, so you have to try yourself whether your debugging tools are up to that.

Answer (score 0):

It is converted back to vanilla JS (babel does that part).
What you get is that you can utilize Classes which I found useful.

Hopefully with time, browsers will support ES6 and we will not need babel.

The only drawback is that when debugging, you have to produce a source map, but that is temporary, see above.

To answer your second question: I'm using React in one of the websites, and most of the modules I needed (from npm) are using ES6.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the trade-offs or drawbacks that you mention both do not apply to developing nodejs code using babel as ES7 transpiler. Personally, I find using ES7 features with node tremendously productive.

There is source map support for debugging. I use karma for testing and it comes with excellent source map support (I use IntelliJ but I believe most IDEs will do). You can checkout this [REST-API](https://github.com/open-medicine-initiative/rest-api) repository on github. It's a nice stack for building nodejs data backend. It uses karma for testing - even comes with code coverage support. It also integrates with pm2 for scaling and availability.

Regarding performance: I think transpiled code has been shown to run faster in many scenarios than the code a developer would write when not having advanced language features available. I will post some links later.